# "to pull all of the data" vs "to pull all the data"

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrase-usage

I have these two phrases: "to pull all of the data" and "to pull all the data".
The second phrase seems a bit off, but it's used a lot in technical writing, so I guess I'm missing something.

Does the meaning change?
Are both grammatically correct?

And finally, what's the purpose of "of" in the first example?

Comment: The answers to ["All our X" vs. "all of our X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65650/all-our-x-vs-all-of-our-x) may be helpful to you.

Comment: To pull all of **the data** off or out of some place. To pull all the data would mean: to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

They both sound fine to me, and sound identical in meaning.